# Can a user who doesn't have permission to read a directory still read files inside it?

Tags: linux, permissions

Is it possible for a user who doesn't have permission to read a directory, but does have permission to read the files inside it, to access those files? If so, how?

Or, put another way: If I want to prevent a user from accessing files in a directory, is revoking that user's permissions for the directory sufficient, or do I have to revoke the user's permissions on all files in the directory as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the exact permissions the user has on the directory.
If the user is allowed to enter the directory (x), he can read files by accessing them with the filename. It is possible to brute-force filenames, of course. He can not list the files in the directory without having read permissions on it. He can, however, try possible filenames and compare the error messages. He will get `Permission denied` in case the file exists or `No such file or directory`, in case it doesn't, obviously.
If the user does not have the right to enter the directory (x), he is not able to read files in it at all.

Comment: So there's no security risk in allowing everyone read permissions to sensitive files so long as the directory those files are in has permissions set appropriately?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure whether I understood your question correctly. Do you want to revoke read permissions on the directory but grant read permissions on the files inside the directory? Well, I wouldn't say there are _no_ security risks. As I mentioned, it is possible to get access to the files by brute-forcing filenames.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have explained my reasons for asking this in my question. I'm not saying I *want* users to be able to read files in the protected directory, I'm just asking whether they can so I know whether I have to take extra precautions to prevent them from doing so.

Comment: Short answer: they can. If you don't want them to, revoke the permissions.

Comment: So which is it? Your answer says that they can't if they don't have read or execute permissions on the directory, but your comment says that they can.

Comment: Once again: if they have neither read nor execute permissions, they can't. If they just have execute permissions, they can brute force it. If they have read permissions, they can. I'm not sure what is causing your misunderstanding. Please be more specific if you are not sure about your specific use case.

Comment: No problem, I think I've got it now.

I was just confused because your answer says they can't if they have no permissions on the directory, but in your comment you said 'Short answer: they can.' Thanks for clearing that up.